# Limit the subquery results in DQL

Tags: symfony, dql

I want to use LIMIT 1 clausule on the subquery in SELECT in DQL query...How can I do that?

```
"SELECT partial p.{productId, productName, count, price, utwTs},
                       (
                           SELECT pp.fileName
                           FROM AdminBundle:ProductPhoto pp 
                           WHERE pp.productId = p.productId 
                           // LIMIT 1 <--- here
                       ) AS photo_name,
                       u.avatarName     
                FROM AdminBundle\Entity\Product p
                LEFT JOIN AdminBundle\Entity\Users u WITH u.id = p.userId
                LEFT JOIN AdminBundle\Entity\Shop sh WITH sh.userId = u.id
                LEFT JOIN AdminBundle\Entity\Stand s WITH p.standId = s.standId
                WHERE p.active = 1 and p.productId > 0";
```

How can I do this? I can't use native sql, becuase pagination (knpbundle) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible for security reasons ...

see this -> http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-885

eventually you can still make you subquery into a query and limit results with ->setMaxResults( XX ) , et use it into your main query.